# Angular JS Test driven Development with multiple controllers

Tags: angularjs, tdd, karma-jasmine

I have developed an web application using Angular JS. I am getting few additional CR which needs to implemented in using TTD approach. We have return unit test cases using Jasmine and Karma. The challenge currently we face is when we try to write unit test case for multiple controllers. I have a main page return on Home Controller & its has an broadcast event in another controller. When i write a unit test case Object for the controller which has this broadcast event is not initialized.

Is there any way to inject the second controller as a dependent object. Answers with Reference Sample link or demo code is much appreciated.

Comment: I think your test method's thread is emiting as uniq thread becouse of cross library couldnt have multy thread.
You can try to write an event initatialization factory on your main controller for special test cases. I havent had this just i think

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You state you are using Jasmine and Karma so I assume you are unit testing. If you are "unit" testing you should test each controller individually while mocking, spy, all injected services.

```
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        rootScope = $rootScope;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('MyCtrl as ctrl', {
            '$scope': scope
        });            
    }));

    it('', function(){

     //Arrange
     controller.counter = 0; // Your controller is listening on scope.$on to update this counter.

     //Act
     rootScope.$broadcast('xyz', {});

     //Assert
     expect(controller.counter == 1).toBe(true);
     rootScope.$broadcast('xyz', {});
     expect(controller.counter == 2).toBe(true);
     rootScope.$broadcast('xyz', {});
     expect(controller.counter == 3).toBe(true);
    });
```

Just be careful with broadcast.  Only a domain events (model updated/deleted/created), or something global (signin,signout) should travel over $broadcast.  Otherwise, it should be replaced with a service + directive.  An example is angular material https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog  that is 1 directive with a backing service that can be open/closed from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can inject any controller with the $controller service, e.g.

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller('MyCtrl', {
                '$scope': scope
            });
        }));
```

see docs here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$controller

so what you do is inject that controller first, then your other controller. then the first controller will have been instantiated at the time the second gets instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to angular, it seems to be possible to inject multiple controllers at once. However best practice is to generate a mock controller that behaves as you expect the second controller to behave. This reduces the number of things you are testing at once. 
The following link may be helpful for creating a mock controller, http://www.powdertothepeople.tv/2014/08/28/Mocking-Controller-Instantiation-In-AngularJS-Unit-Test/ .